# htaccess rule to process all requests through index.php but images and web resources WITH a query string

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I'm writing or implementing a PHP based URI router for an existing website and would like to pass all URL requests through index.php (or router.php or whatever file).

I've successfully accomplished this by using the following htacces file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.js|\.css|\.ico)$
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^size=([a-z]*)$
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php [QSA]
```

This code routes everything through index.php as expected, but some image requests need a query string for responsive sizing.

for example `www.mydomain.com/images/my_great_image.jpg?size=small`

as you can see I've been attempting some kind of solution (second commented line of code), however I'm simply not very good either at Regexes nor Apache rules.

Those query strings should always have the same pattern ^?size=* and different query strings shouldn't be passed.

And also shouldn't fight the responsive images rewrite rule beforehand. (which precedes the index.php rewrite rules)

```
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php
```

Thanks for your help!

PD: I'm looking into adding a fairly simple URL router, any good PHP based suggestions?

I've been looking into [chriso/klein.php](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php)
and [nikic/FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)

Comment: You have the QSA flag so it will pass any query string attached however you can ignore anything sent but the "Size" string in your code.

Comment: Makes sense, but this doesn't allow `my_great_image.jpg?size=small` through as a normal file, but routes it through index.php instead.

Comment: It is not clear why do you need both `RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php` rule and `index.php` rules handling same image files?

Comment: @anubhava I don't want images to be procesed by index.php and adaptive-images.php

I want images regardless whether they have a query string or not to go straight to adaptive-images.php and everything else go to index.php

Comment: ok then isn't Jon's answer working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably make it so the adaptive images php file is also **excluded** by the index.php routing rule. The rewrite engine loops so the first rule that rewrites to the php file will end up being trapped by the index.php rule. Try:

```
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.js|\.css|\.ico|\.php)$
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php [QSA,L]
```

If the goal is to *only* allow `adaptive-images.php` through without getting routed to `index.php` then you need to add a new condition:

```
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.js|\.css|\.ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !adaptive-images\.php
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well... this works!

I'd love to know why.

Not sure what the L flag does, and adding the extra |\.php 

Thanks!

Comment: @Sandman21dan the `L` flag stops rewriting and adding the `\.php` into that list of extensions to exclude prevents any php file from getting route to `index.php`.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this, but actually, this matches all .php files. So, yeah it allows for clean links, but also allows users to navigate any .php file in my file system, which is kind of exactly what I'm trying to prevent. Now I question, is what I want fully achievable by .htaccess? or should I simply redirect absolutely all (to index.php) and parse every URI from there?

Comment: @Sandman21dan If you only want to prevent adaptive images from getting routed to index.php then don't add the `.php` to the list and instead add a second rewrite condition right under that line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !adaptive-images\.php

Comment: Spot On!. That's what I meant from the beginning! Don't know if you should edit the answer so I can select it as the answer or just select as is. Thanks!